# LinkedIn Javascript SDK authorize stopped working

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have a LinkedIn integration using their SDK and use the method `authorize` to request permission from the user to post in her/his behalf. It was working fine but today I noticed that it stopped working. The issue is that the `callbackFunction` (see https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) never gets called, so I don't know when the user grants permission or not.

I was checking and noticed that the file: https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js now redirects to https://platform.linkedin.com/xdoor/scripts/in.js. I took a look at https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js and it seems that it changed around November the 13th.

Have you had any problems with the SDK recently?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you found any status on this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't been able to find anything. 

I found a workaround for it though. The `isAuthorized` does return `true` after the user has granted access so I could use an interval to check when that becomes `true` and manually invoke the callback.

Comment: We are having the same issues, as well as a few others posting, since the js code change. We have not changed our code, and it was working on the 12th.

Comment: have you reported it to linkedin?

Comment: @Thayne I have a support case opened and am waiting to hear back. But their support cases are supposed to be for linkedin.com issues, not API questions.
Their developer SDK documentation recommends asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have in mind that LinkedIn posted recently `SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps.` (https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates). I think that is a kind of abrupt change, but it seems that soon (probably in 2019-03-01 or before) LinkedIn will only accept Oauth2 authentication.

Comment: Read the documentation of LinkedIn OAuth2, It's only giving access for Android and Ios, not Web.

Comment: As well as through this link:- https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk  . Now support is also not available for javascript sdk. I faced this issue recently. I raised  a ticket regarding too, but didn't get any answer